# Hibernate Spring could not resolve property basic query

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

Im trying to execute a very basic query and Im receiving the org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property.
This is my entity:

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "pm_screenconfiguration")
public class ScreenConfiguration extends PubliMovilEntity {

```
/**
 * serial.
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5337034940299810600L;

@Id
@Column(name = "code")
private String code;

@Id
@Column(name = "companyCode")
private int companyCode;

@Id
@Column(name = "applicationId")
private int applicationId;


@Column(name = "value")
private String value;


/**
 * @return the code
 */
public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

/**
 * @param code the code to set
 */
public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

/**
 * @return the value
 */
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

/**
 * @param value the value to set
 */
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

/**
 * @return the companyCode
 */
public int getCompanyCode() {
    return companyCode;
}

/**
 * @param companyCode the companyCode to set
 */
public void setCompanyCode(int companyCode) {
    this.companyCode = companyCode;
}

/**
 * @return the applicationId
 */
public int getApplicationId() {
    return applicationId;
}

/**
 * @param applicationId the applicationId to set
 */
public void setApplicationId(int applicationId) {
    this.applicationId = applicationId;
}
```

}

and this is my query:

```
public List<BaseEntity> getList(BaseSearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
    Criteria criteria = getSessionFactory() .openSession().createCriteria(ScreenConfiguration.class);
    if (searchCriteria.getApplicationId() != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("applicationId", searchCriteria.getApplicationId()));
    }

    if (searchCriteria.getCompanyCode() != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("companyCode", searchCriteria.getCompanyCode()));
    }

    return criteria.list();
}
```

I really can't figure it out. Im using MySql and all the columns have the same name of the entity.

Thanks.

Comment: please show code for PubliMovilEntity and stackTrace

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the @Id fields declarations. 
When a primary key is composed for more than one field you have to specify an IdClass. (There are another ways using @Embbeded annotation).

I've created an IdClass with the fields that I annoted with @Id and in the entity I have a reference for that IdClass.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pm_screenconf")
@IdClass(ScreenConfigurationPK.class)
public class ScreenConfiguration extends PubliMovilEntity {
```

See: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/ - 
thanks.